# ListView item longClick

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview, onitemlongclicklistener

I have a ListFragment, to which I attach some headers(a WebView among other stuff) and footers. I understand that Android handles the onLongClick event of WebViews to show a CAB with copy/paste to/from Clipboard. This is perfectly fine for me, but my problem is that whenever I long click on WebView's content, to show the CAB, this view (header of ListView), automatically scrolls to the bottom of it.

This seems like it is a default action for a ListView item longClick, so my question is, how can I override this thing (of autoscrolling to the bottom of the longClicked item), without damaging other stuff (like for example: if I long click on an item that doesn't need the CAB with copy/paste to appear, than ListView should handle it as it already does). I tried Overriding the onItemLongClick method of the ListView to return false (so it will pass the returning further, but it doesn't necessarily seem to do what I'd like it to do, and it creates a strange bug).

Basicly (I think) if the item that user long clicks on contains a WebView, I need to dispatch the longClick event to the WebView, otherwise ListView should handle it.

LE: I tested out against a fresh small sample of a ListFragment with a long(larger than the screen) WebView as its header, and is seems like it doesn't autoscroll to the bottom of the Header on LongClick on WebView. That being said, I can't see what could I do to create such action. Any ideas would be much appreciated, maybe I`m mistakely overlooking some small thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a very long while to determine what was the problem to this issue, but finally I managed to do it.

this very line:

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

in the Activity was messing up everything. Hope that this will help someone else to not lose so much time on it.

PS. It can be reproduced with

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

in xml too.

Answer (score 0):

after you've devined your listAdaper:e.g:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            list,
            R.layout.playlist_view,
            new String[] {"fileName","path"},
            new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
    );
```

setOnLongClickListener

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setOnLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
//Ovverride onItemLongClick click here (requires API 20+)
```

P.S: In my project list is

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
```

Example of override long click:

```
public abstract boolean onItemLongClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id
{
Intent service=new Intent(YourClassName.this,ClassToNavigate.class);
            service.putExtra("ElementPosition",position);
            service.putExtra("SelectedFromList",true);
            startService(service);
 }
```

Comment: How should the method onItemLongClick body look like? I already said I tried doing this w/o proper result. The trick lies within that method's body.

Comment: please try that I've attached code to override. I didn't try that but it should work @DoruAdryan
position is position of the element of your list (starts with 0 ;))

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not satisfied with the answer. You're telling me how to create a random onItemLongClick, but that's not something I want or need. Like I said, when I long click on the content of the headerview (which contains a WebView among other views), the default Android CAB appears and highlights the tapped word, which is ok. But the problem is that it scrolls down to the bottom of the header, and I have to scroll back to the hightlighted word manually. The problem may not lie inside the ListView listener at all, that was just my homble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an OnItemLongClickListener to your list. In it's callback you can check if the long clicked row is the webview by checking the position corresponds to it and return true for this case

Comment: So basicly, what you say is that I check whenever I longClick on a ListView item, and check if among the views that lies within that item, there is a WebView, and if that's the case than WebView should handle it. Question is: Can I do smth like if I long click on a WebView, I would "request" the need to handle that action (in other words, "hey ListView, let me handle this")? And if yes, can you provide an example ?