# ListView with WebView as Header autoscrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

I have this situation, where I created a `ListFragment` to which I attached a `HeaderView`, containing a long `WebView` among other Views. 
I started this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420603/listview-item-longclick/26461886#26461886) where I explained quite detailed the situation, in which whenever an user tried to *long tap* on the `WebView` content, in order to: let's just say copy a phrase from it and paste it somewhere else, it gets automatically scrolled to the bottom of the HeaderView.

I created a simple example ([gist](https://gist.github.com/DoruAdryan/386c93b8465313a878b0) here), in which I prove the behavior so I can be understood more easily. The layouts for it are just simple layouts, nothing out of the ordinary. (a `FrameLayout` for the `Activity` and a `WebView` for the `ListFragment headeView`).

As I mentioned in the thread above, this issue of autoscrolling can be 'corrected' by removing the

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

line, and everything works ok, but I need my Activity to hide the actionbar/titlebar for it to be in compliance with the design. I tried using `ActionBarActivity` with `getSupportActionBar().hide()`, but with the same autoscrolling issue outcome.

What can I do to manipulate this into the desired result?

LE: I have a feeling that somehow I could get access to the default behaviour of onLongClick on the WebView and after calling that default method I could return true, so that the event wont' be dispatched any further (aka to ListView). I searched everywhere but I can not find this piece of code to fire the default behaviour (startActionMode with selection and copy/paste I presume) on onLongClick.

LE2: the layouts are like this: 
MainActivity layout contains a FrameLayout with match_parent height/width.
HeaderView is a layout containing a match_parent height/width WebView.

This is headerview layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wv_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Where is your R.layout.act_main? If you want someone to help you. You should provide all info :)

Comment: MainActivity layout only has a match_parent width/height FrameLayout. There is nothing out of the ordinary. I reedited post with this info too.

Comment: I copy pasted your gist but these were not found "R.id.container_list" ((WebView) header.findViewById(R.id.wv_test)),R.layout.frag_header and other so many

Comment: @AZ_ I changed with headerView layout too. R.id.container_list is the id of the FrameLayout to which I added the ListFragment

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that you put a scrollable view (webview) as part of another scrollable view (listview) you should try to create a custom webview and override the onTouchEvent method in this way:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);       
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

this should disable the parent of the webview (listview) to intercept touch events

Comment: Your answer might be on the right path I was visualising, but it needs some more working. The reason I am saying that, is that now the listview won't scroll at all (prob because my CustomWebView is 'stealing' that event), so what I need to do, is make this requestDissallowInterceptTouchEvent happen only when I longClick on the WebView. Could you assist me into solving this?

Comment: The best thing you could do is set requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); when you touch the webview and false when you touch the listview, the only problem is that you'll need to touch the screen every time you want to change the intercept. Otherwise if you don't need the header to scroll away with your list you could just separate them.